# Save terminal buffer's current working directory with mksession

Tags: terminal-buffer, sessions

I usually start vim at the root of my project. Then I open tabs with windows inside. Usually one of the windows has a `:terminal`. In the `:terminal`, I usually `cd to/some/subfolder`.

At the end of the day, I run `:mksession` to save my tab/window layout. However, one thing I notice is that my `:terminal`s forget what folder I was in. This means at the start of every day I have to go to each `:terminal` window and run `cd to/some/subfolderA`, `cd to/some/subfolderB`, etc.

Is there a way to record the current working directory of each of my `:terminal` windows in my `:mksession` file? The cwd of the vim process is fine at the root of my project. I only care about the subterminals that vim creates.

Ideally this would be able to be done without a plugin or as little config as possible.

These are my session options.

```
sessionoptions=blank,buffers,curdir,folds,help,options,tabpages,winsize,terminal
```